# In the below code I want to add if statement for GridViewBind() where in the else case I want to say "NO DATA TO DISPLAY"

Tags: c#, ado.net

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString);

SqlDataAdapter dadapter;
DataSet dset; "SELECT Buildingsection from  Building_Section";// Another Table

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        dadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
        dset = new DataSet();
        dadapter.Fill(dset);
        DropDownList1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Buildingsection ";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Buildingsection ";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        GridViewBind();
    }
}
  protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewBind();
    }
    public void GridViewBind()
    {
        dadapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from SocoetyMaintan where Id=" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "", con);
        dset = new DataSet();
        dadapter.Fill(dset);
        GridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Basically what do you want to achieve? Can you please be more specific? and also post .aspx code with proper format.

Comment: if selected item from dropdownlist is not equals to existing item in the table then i want to show there is no data to display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked to solve the problem for me:

```
if (dset.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0) 
{ 
    Label1.Visible = true; 
    Label1.Text = "No Data To Display!"; 
} 
else Label1.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create another text field/control with text **“NO DATA TO DISPLAY”**. It will be hidden by default. Show it when condition does not satisfy and hide the grid.

Otherwise clean up the `gridview` data and insert the text **“NO DATA TO DISPLAY”** in first entry.

Comment: Understood  Sir, need to know that condition,

Comment: if (dset.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
                        {
                            Label1.Text = "No Data To Display!";
                        }

Comment: see i found above solution but the lable is executing repetedly, can you please  help me in this case   @ManishM